# Is there a way to filter an Azure DevOps board using dates?

Tags: azure-devops

On the Boards section of Azure DevOps, there's a nice filter bar.  It contains filters for:

- Type
- Assigned to
- Tags
- Iteration
- Area
- Parent work item

[image: board]

As far as I can see, there's no way to use the section outlined in yellow to filter for work items (for example) created within the last seven days, or due within the next 14 days.

Things I've tried:

1. Creating a query and viewing results as a board (can't see an option to do that)
2. Finding a way to script work items into iterations based on date, and then filtering the board based on iteration

Is there a way to do this?  It's specifically a board I'd like, as opposed to a Backlog-style list.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? In the similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the board's settings, Is this what you want?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not exactly.  It's the Board I'd like to filter, not the list of work items.  I've added a screenshot to the question to clarify